# React/Redux preloading content from API response before page renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am currently building a web app which contains a menu. The menu can change depending on a couple of variables, and so I make a call to an api, to request the correct menu items that should be shown.

```
server.get('/api/getMenu', (req, res) => {
    getMenu((err, content) => {
        if(!err) {
            res.send(content);
        } else {
            res.status(500).send();
        }
    })
});
```

This request is working perfectly fine, and I am then dispatching an action that will call this API on componentWillMount

```
export function fetchMenuItems() {
    return (dispatch) => {
        fetch('/api/getMenu')
            .then((response) => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw Error(response.statusText);
                }

                return response;
            })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((results) => dispatch(fetchSuccess(results)))
    }
}

export function fetchSuccess(results) {
    return {
        type: 'FETCH_SUCCESS',
        menuItems: results
    };
}
```

This again is working fine and loading the menu items, however it looks strange as the menu items seem to render on the page after the rest of the page has already loaded (I'm assuming due to how long the request takes).

Is there any way to preload the menu items before the whole page actually renders? I've heard of promises but know little of them, would this potentially be a solution?

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming you're looking for componentWillMount react lifecycle method.

`componentWillMount` will be invoked only once right before your component rendered at the first time. This is a perfect place to put any pre-loading data logic.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is what I'm doing at the moment, but the items still load after a significant amount of the page because it's an async action. My question was around how I can run this async action before page load so that the menu items are already loaded.

Comment: In that case, I suggest you to try combinelatest api of rxjs: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/combinelatest.md